# Self Referencing SQL query when condition is met

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query to return the column values from a table that meet certain criteria.

Currently I have used the CONCAT function to join the first and last names into a single column in the query result for employees that have the role of 'Programmer'.

```
SELECT
    person.id, CONCAT(person.firstname,' ', person.lastname) AS FULLNAME 
FROM 
    person, role 
WHERE 
    person.role_id = role.id AND role.name = 'Programmer'
```

This successfully runs and returns all programmers from the tables. Notice in my table structure I have an `actingas_id` column. This is the key to another person.id for people who are working on behalf of another people whilst they're on leave from work.

Thus, we arrive at my Question: How do I modify the SQL query such that when a person is **acting** that the query retrieves the first and last name of this person as well as the person who's 'shoes are being filled'?

My table structure is as follows:

**person:**   
id  |  firstname   |   lastname   | role_id   |   actingas_id |

**role:**   
id  |  name   |

```
+----+-----------+----------+---------+-------------+
| id | firstname | lastname | role_id | actingas_id |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | John      | Smith    |       1 |           0 |
|  2 | Kevin     | Tull     |       2 |           1 |
|  3 | Michael   | Woods    |       1 |           0 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+-------------+
```

Here Kevin is Acting for for John, and Michael is also a Programmer, so the result of my query should be:

```
+----+-------------------------+
| id |          NAME           |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | John Smith - Kevin Tull |
|  3 | Michael Woods           |
|  x | Other Programmers..     |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Im using a MySQL database in a WAMP setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This untested query should give you the result you whant:

```
SELECT person1.id, CASE WHEN person1.actingas_id =0 then CONCAT(person1.firstname,' ', person1.lastname) else CONCAT(person1.firstname,' ', person1.lastname,' - ',  person2.firstname,' ', person2.lastname)  AS FULLNAME 
FROM person person1 left join person person2 on person1.actingas_id=person2.id
join role on person1.role_id=role.id
WHERE role.name = 'Programmer'
```

Comment: This should be a LEFT JOIN from person1 to person2. otherwise all good.

Comment: @simo.3792095 Thanks I have change the answer

Comment: easy to spot when you format the code a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` to add those additional records:

```
SELECT person.id, 
       CONCAT(person.firstname,' ', person.lastname) AS FULLNAME 
FROM person INNER JOIN role 
  ON person.role_id = role.id 
WHERE role.name = 'Programmer' 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM person p WHERE p.actingas_id = person.id) 
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, 
       CONCAT(a.firstname,' ', a.lastname, ' - ', person.firstname,' ', person.lastname) AS FULLNAME 
FROM person INNER JOIN person a 
  ON a.acting_as = person.id
INNER JOIN role 
  ON person.role_id = role.id 
WHERE role.name = 'Programmer' AND a.actingas_id <> 0
```

Also, avoid using old style comma-separated JOINs. Use INNER JOINs